# Battery of Samsung Galaxy S5 drained in 5 hours on Android 5.0

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, battery-life

I received the over the air android 5.0 update a week ago for my Samsung Galaxy S5. I installed the update and since that the my fully charged battery is depleted in 5 to 8 hours. Before the battery was depleted in 24 to 36 hours.

I have a spare battery with the same behaviour.

Below screenshots of the battery usage. Note the second battery:[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

High battery usage of Google Play Services could be caused by a number of things. A few suggestions I could make to help rectify your issue would be to:

1) Force stop the app; clear the cache and then allow it to restart.
2) Install 'Greenify' from the PlayStore and prevent the app creating wakelocks.
3) If you are rooted; try reflashing an Android L 5.0 Gapps package with recovery.

Comment: I am not rooted. I tried your suggestions. Unfortunately no success

Answer (score 1):

The battery drain is caused by the Samsung stock app 'my magazine'.

If you click on the 'location icon',  located next to your wifi icon, you can see which apps often make location requests:[image: location page shows geonews and unified daemon drain battery]

In this picture can be seen that the 'apps' geo news and unified daemon have a high battery usage. When I stop those apps, battery drain stops. Unfortunately after some time the geonews apps starts itself again.

The solution is to put unified daemon on turn off state:[image: turn off unified daemon to stop battery drain]

And to disable the stock app 'my magazine', which is responsible for geo news, by long pressing the home screen and selecting 'home screen settings': [image] and after that uncheck 'my magazine': [image: uncheck my magazine to stop battery drain]

Now my battery life is back to 24 hours (instead of 4 hours)